# how Class.forName() works in java

Tags: java, maven, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I have a web application and I am loading a class using `Class.forname("com.test.abc")`, and this abc class is present in different jar, all jars are present in `web-inf/lib` folder. but still i am getting ***ClassNotFoundException***.

How does `Class.forname()` works in java? where does it look for the classes?

why I am getting this error? Do I need to add jar where abc is present into maven dependency or manifest file of the jar?

Comment: when are getting error? can you share more details on how are you running the application?

Comment: during run time,  this is a web application

Comment: `abc` is a class or a package?

Comment: yes, it is there in web-inf/lib folder

Comment: @user7294900  abc is class

Comment: is it web-inf/lib is part of project structure or are the jar's present under web-inf/lib after deployment?

Comment: after deplyment its present in web-inf/lib

Comment: It should work in that case. you could verify if the class is present in the jar or not. is your class name is `abc` or `Abc`.

Verify the package path is correct.

Comment: It will use the thread's current classloader if you do not specify one. Where is the code you are loading the class from located? It will for example *not* be able to see the class if you try to load from a jar file that is part of the container. Can you try to use a classloader that can definitely see web-inf/lib? (`SomeClassInTheWebapp.class.getClassLoader()`)

Comment: @Thilo how do i figure out, which classloader can see web-inf/lib

Comment: Take one of your own classes and then do `SomeClassInTheWebapp.class.getClassloader()`. Pass this classloader to `Class.forName` (it has a version that takes such a parameter).

Comment: But why do you need to do `Class.forName` anyway? Cannot you compile against that jar file? Does it really have to be added afterwards?